# как решить ошибку "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Descr iption: Bad Request: chat not found"

Tags: python, telebot

поставил на хостинг бота телеграм(pythonanywhere), и после команды, которая отправляет сообщение всем пользователям которые зарегистировались в боте, То есть рассылка сообщения, выходит ошибка:

> 515 (**init**.py:489 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Descr
> iption: Bad Request: chat not found"

но бот продолжает работать. файлы подключил, всё правильно указал, в user_ids.txt есть иды юзеров:

```
# записывание идов для рассылки-----------------
joinedFile = open('/home/timur1kupcov/user_ids.txt', "r")
joinedUsers = set()
for line in joinedFile:
    joinedUsers.add(line.strip())
joinedFile.close()
# ----------------------------------------------
# записывание идов с команды /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def startJoin(message):
    if not str(message.chat.id) in joinedUsers:
        joinedFile = open('/home/timur1kupcov/user_ids.txt', "a")
        joinedFile.write(str(message.chat.id) + "\n")
        joinedUsers.add(message.chat.id)
# команда для рассылки
@bot.message_handler(commands=['specialrass'])
def mess(message):
    for user in joinedUsers:
        bot.send_message(user, message.text[message.text.find(' '):])
```

Comment: отредактируйте свой код, путём правки, добавив ошибку и код в виде текста.

Comment: Никто не будет отвечать на вопрос, где код выложен в картинках (еще и обрезанных). если вы думаете, что вас какой-то эксклюзивный код, то таких вопросов по нескольку в день )))

Comment: @Violet, Сейчас

Comment: пользователи начали диалог с ботом? бот не может писать первым.

Comment: @Violet, в user_ids те пользователи которые начали диалог с ботом

Comment: Приведите пример содержимого users_ids и `type(user)`

Comment: я подумал что возможно что какой то пользователь заблокировал бота, и бот не смог отправить сообщение и поломался. я поштучно убирал иды юзеров и удалил одну строку пользователя и бот заработал.
теперь проблема возникла с pythonanywhere.
после обновления консоли, нужно было переустанавливать модули, и возникает такая ошибка:                         
  File "/home/timur1kupcov/bot.py", line 3, in <module>
    import telebot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'
попробовал установить pyTelegramBotAPI модуль,но ошибка продолжала писаться